# How to update Map object property values?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a best way to update object property values which are on Map, however it seems like there isn't a specific function for this.

Example:

```
const map = new Map();
map.set('kfwwwdvh', { first: 1, second: 2});
```

Now I would like to update 'first' property value, but if I do this

```
map.set('kfwwwdvh', { first: 'updated value'});
```

It will output this:

```
{ first: 'updated value'}
```

My question is how do I update object property values without overwriting other values the object has (in this example 'second' property and value), what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to set the value on the map key by overriding that `first` value as follows.

```
map.set('kfwwwdvh', {
  ...map.get('kfwwwdvh'),
  first: 'updated value'
});
```

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set('kfwwwdvh', { first: 1, second: 2});
console.log(map.get('kfwwwdvh'));

map.set('kfwwwdvh', {
  ...map.get('kfwwwdvh'),
  first: 'updated value'
});
console.log(map.get('kfwwwdvh'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can update the property by first retrieving the object from the map using `.get()`, and then update the property of the returned object reference like so:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('kfwwwdvh', { first: 1, second: 2});

map.get('kfwwwdvh').first = 'updated value';
console.log(map.get('kfwwwdvh'));
```

This will update the actual object in place, meaning if any references of it reside anywhere they will also be updated. This may be a good or bad thing depending on what behaviour you're after. For example:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('kfwwwdvh', { first: 1, second: 2});
const obj = map.get('kfwwwdvh');

map.get('kfwwwdvh').first = 'updated value';
console.log(map.get('kfwwwdvh'), obj); // both updated
```